# How Define Some Variables in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How can Convert This Code :

```
$_POST['search']['value']
if($_POST['length'] != -1)

($_POST['length'], $_POST['start'])
```

To Codeigniter 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($this->input->post("search"){    
   $this->input->post("search")['value']; //$_POST['search']['value']
}

if($this->input->post("length") && $this->input->post("start")){
    ($this->input->post("length"),$this->input->post("start")) //($_POST['length'], $_POST['start'])
}
```

**[Check Reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#id5)**

Comment: Check this `if($this->input->post("length"))`

Comment: bro first thank you but show error with all Variables Message: Undefined index: search

Comment: still error with  if($this->input->post("search"){    
   $this->input->post("search")['value']; //$_POST['search']['value']
}